# $a^{1/n}$ is uniquely determined

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

Just wanting to check the reasoning in this proof -- I'm using the notation $(\eta^n)^{-1}$ instead of $\eta^{-n}$ since the latter hasn't yet been introduced in my text.

To be clear I'm not looking for alternative/simpler proofs, just was hoping to confirm the reasoning in this proof, or understand where I've gone wrong.

**Theorem.** Let $a \geq 0$. For each positive integer $n$ define $a^{1/n}$ to be a number $\beta$ such that $\beta^n = a$, and $\beta \geq 0$. Then such a number $\beta$, if it exists, is uniquely determined.

**Proof.** Suppose there exist two numbers $\beta\geq0$ and $\alpha\geq 0$ such that $\beta^n = a$, $\alpha^n = a$ for $a \geq 0$.

If $a = 0$, then $\alpha = \beta = 0$.

Otherwise, $a > 0$. Then we have $$\alpha^n = \beta^n  = a$$

Multiplying through by $(\beta^{n})^{-1}$ we obtain

$$
\beta^n (\beta^{n})^{-1} = 1 = \alpha(\beta^{n})^{-1}
$$

Then $(\beta^{n})^{-1} = (\alpha^{n})^{-1}$. Since multiplicative inverses are unique, we have  $(\alpha^{n})^{-1} = (\beta^{n})^{-1}$, and so it must be that $\alpha^n = \beta^n$ and hence $\alpha = \beta$ (which can be shown inductively). $\square$

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing with inverses. You already have $\alpha^n = \beta^n=a$ why trying to show that $\alpha^n = \beta^n$ that you already know?

Comment: Thanks -- that's a great point. So maybe a better argument then is just an inductive argument showing that $\alpha^{n} = \beta^{n} \implies \alpha = \beta$?

Comment: Yes I was going to point that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you are allowed to use but I am suggesting:

**Algebraic approach** : for $a>0$, if we have $a=\alpha^n = \beta^n$ then $\alpha^n-\beta^n=0$ therefore : $$ (\alpha-\beta)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha^i\beta^{n-1-i}=0 $$ and as $\alpha,\beta>0$ (otherwise we would have $a = \alpha^n = \beta^n= 0^n =0$ which is impossible) then all of their positive powers are strictly positive and hence:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha^i\beta^{n-1-i}>0$$

Consequently:

$$ \alpha-\beta = 0 \text{ i.e. }\boxed{\alpha = \beta}$$